# Is it possible to keep a connection with two different MQTT Brokers when using the Node-RED?

Tags: mqtt, node-red

I have a server on the cloud that receives `MQTT` messages and I'm running the `Node-RED` on a `Raspberry pi` on my localhost...

With the Raspberry, I'm receiving data from different devices using the `MQTT protocol`. And until here, it works great! The problem is when I try to receive messages from the `MQTT` broker that's running locally (on the Raspberry) and then send these messages to other `MQTT` broker that's running on another server. Something like this image:

[image: Example]

When I try to use two different brokers with the Node-RED, it automatically updates all other nodes to the last broker that I had configured. So, is it possible to open a connection with two different `MQTT` Brokers when I'm using the `Node-RED`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the MQTT node edit dialog, the 'Server' field is a select box. It lists all of the broker configurations you have in your flow.

To add a connection to a different broker, select the 'Add new mqtt-broker...' option then click the button next to the select box.

That adds a new connection configuration rather than edit the one already being used by your existing nodes.